# Amazon SNS Message Structure Not working

Tags: push-notification, amazon-sns

```
{
   "default":"This is the default Message",
    "APNS_SANDBOX":{
                     "aps":{
                            "alert":{
                                      "title":"JustFollow",
                                      "body":"ABc"
                                     }
                            }
                    },
     "GCM":{
              "data":{
                       "message":"abc"
                      }
            }
}
```

This is the Josn mesage which will be send at the time when Amazon Notification is Published, But when on Mobile we get the Notification, it will taking nothing Except "default tag". I want to Fetch GCM and APNS_SandBox Details.

SEND NOTIFICATION CODE

```
_amazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient.Publish(new PublishRequest
      {
          Subject = StringConstant.ApplicationName,
          Message = "abc",
          //MessageStructure ="json",
          TopicArn = topicArn
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sending message format in below format, it is working properly.

```
{
"default":"abc",
"GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"12\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"}}",
"APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"12\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"} }"
}
```

Comment: For production in Ios, insted of APNS_SANDBOX, we have to Use APNS